# How can I change the shape default in Preview app?

Tags: macos, preview

Every time I click on the oval shape in Preview, I get a big ellipse filled in opaque blue.
How do I change this **default** such that every time I click on the oval, I get a transparent circle with a black border?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To remove the fill colour, click on the [orange] square and choose white colour, which is transparent behaviour.
The border colour can be changed by clicking on the [red] square and choose whatever you need.

Comment: These instructions are for changing the color and border **after** I select the shape. I was looking for information on how to set the **default** before I select the shape, so that the shape gets drawn with desired properties.

Comment: The operation is the same: go to View and select "Show markup Toolbar" if this is not already opened, and go to the each square mentioned in my answer and configure as you wish. Next time you open Preview, it will shows up your selection.

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled into this while waiting for your reply. I can change the colors, but I still can't see how to change the default shape to a circle of a certain size. Any thoughts there?

Comment: As you can see, there is not any "default" value for shapes or colours, so you must just generate one oval and then modify it as you wish.